# Find the number of triples (i, j, k) in array such that A[i] + A[j] = 2 * A[k]

Tags: c++, math

How to finds the number of tuplets/pairs i, j, k in array such that a[i] + a[j] = 2 * a[k]. The complexity should be O(n * logn) or O(n) since n <= 10^5.

Edit 2(important): abs(a[i]) <= 10^3.

Edit:
i, j, k must all be distinct.

Here is my code, but it's too slow, it's complexity O(is n^2 logn).

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int binarna(vector<int> a, int k){
    int n = a.size();
    int low = 0, high = n - 1; 
    bool b = false;

    int mid;
    while(low <= high){
        mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (a[mid] == k){
            b = true;
            break;
        }

        if (k < a[mid])
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            low = mid + 1;
    }

    if (b)
        return mid;
    else
        return -1;
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector<int> a(n);
    for (auto& i : a)
        cin >> i;

    sort(a.begin(), a.end());

    int sol = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i){
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j){
            if ((a[i] + a[j]) % 2)
                continue;
            int k = (a[i] + a[j]) / 2;

            if (binarna(a, k) != -1)
                ++sol;
        }
    }

    cout << sol << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Is `i==j==k` a valid answer or are there additional constraints? What have you tried so far? SO is not a code-writing site.

Comment: Looks like you could use some `for` loops.

Comment: @RichardCritten Values *"in array"*, it's not just the indices

Comment: You're doing a lot of unnecessary copies by passing `a` into the function by value.

Comment: For every `i != j` compute `a[i] + i[j]`.   If it is odd, there is no `k`.   Otherwise, search the array to find the element equal to `(a[i] + i[j])/2`.   If there is one, you have a solution.    You might also want to constrain the question:  are array elements unique?  Is the array sorted? [Your code appears to be attempting to use binary search, which suggests the array is sorted at least, but that is not specified in the question].

Comment: We can observe that `i < k < j`. Now, we can just loop over all pairs `(i, j)` where `i >= j + 2`, and if the sum is even, binary search for `k` between `i` and `j`. Assuming you sort the array first of course.

Comment: That's the best I can think of, although it seems like it's still too slow. I'm thinking there might be a solution involving dynamic programming.

Comment: @Peter: your brute force proposal has complexity O(N³), the worse you can think about, and worse than what the OP already has.

Comment: @Peter It is not said that the array is sorted, but it can be sorted, since it does not make a difference in number of pairs.

Comment: @Morgana - it may not make a difference to number of pairs.  But it does certainly affect choice of algorithm to find the pairs, and therefore ability to meet the complexity requirements.   Also, if the array needs to be sorted in order to use a more efficient algorithm to find pairs, there is a question of whether indices found need to be specified in terms of original sort order.

Comment: @Peter: the lower bound is large enough to make the cost of sorting neglectible. And the locations of the triples is not asked.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity can't probably be better than `O(N²)` because in the case of elements forming a single arithmetic progression, all pairs `(i, j)` with `j-i` even have a suitable element in the middle and the count is `O(N²)`*.

An `O(N²)` solution is as follows:

- sort the array increasingly;
- for every `i`,

  - set `k=i` and for every `j>i`,

    - increment `k` until `2 A[k] >= A[i] + A[j]`
    - increment the count if equality is achieved

For a given `i`, `j` and `k` are monotonously increasing up to `N` so that the total number of operations is `O(N-i)`. This justifies the global behavior `O(N²)`, which is optimal.

---

*There is a little subtlety here as you might contradict the argument by claiming: "we can identify that the array forms an arithmetic sequence in time `O(N)`, and from this compute the count in a single go".

But if instead of a single arithmetic sequence, we have two of them of length `N/2`, the quadratic behavior of the count remains even if they are intertwined. And there are at least `N` ways to intertwine two arithmetic sequences.

---

If the range of elements is much smaller than their number, it is advantageous to compress the data by means of an histogram.

The triple detection algorithm simplifies a little because `k` is systematically `(i+j)/2`. Every triple now counts for `Hi.Hk.Hj` instead of `1`. The complexity is `O(M²)`, where `M` is the size of the histogram.

Comment: I may be wrong, but O(n^2) is too slow. I have one n^2 code (the one I wrote), but don't think that will be fast enough since n <= 10^5. Correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: @Morgana: your code is O(N²Log N), not O(N²). And if you believe my argument, it is not possible to be faster than O(N²) in the worst case.

Comment: I forgot one major thing to say! Didn't see that... abs(a[i)] <= 10^3

Comment: @Morgana: yes, with this info the problem is very different and a solution will probably be histogram based.

Comment: How can I use histogram in this, I'm not quite sure?

Comment: @Morgana: think that a histogram regroups equal elements.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call `D` - total number of distinct values in the array. If `abs(a[i]) <= 10^3`, then you can't have more than `2*10^3` distinct values in the array. It means that if you are a bit smart, complexity of your algorithm becomes minimum of `O(D^2*log(D))` and `O(N*log(N))` which is far better than `O(N^2*log(N))` and if you use smart algorithm suggested by Yves, you get minimum of `O(D^2*log(D))` and `O(N*log(N))`.

Obviously `O(N*log(N))` comes from sorting and you can't avoid it but that's OK even for `N = 10^5`. So how to reduce `N` to `D` in the main part of the algorithm? It is not hard. What you need is to replace the array of `int` values with an array of tuples `(value, count)` (let's call it `B`). It is easy to get such an array by scanning the original array after it is being sorted. The size of this new array is `D` (instead of `N`). Now you apply your algorithm or Yves improved algorithm to this array but each time you find a triplet `(i,j,k)` such that

```
2*B[k].value == B[i].value + B[j].value
```

you increment your total counter by

```
totalCount += B[k].count * B[i].count * B[j].count
```

Why this works? Consider the original sorted array. When you find a triplet `(i,j,k)` such that

```
2*A[k].value == A[i].value + A[j].value
```

You actually find 3 ranges for `i`, `j` and `k` such that in each range values are equal and so you can pick any number from the corresponding range. And simple combinatorics suggest the formula above.